# FOR EACH two tables with WHERE clause OpenEdge

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I'm trying to add together two tables based on their common field which is ProductID, I'm using OpenEdge Editor and when I run this progress file, I get no output or no warning message.

```
FOR EACH table1, EACH table2 WHERE table1.ProductID = table2.ProductID:
    DISPLAY table1.ProductID.
END.
```

Comment: A point of note: whilst this is only dummy code to illustrate a point, it's a good idea to get in the habit of always specifying a lock type.

Comment: What is the idea behind lock type?

Comment: There are three types of lock statement in Progress. NO-LOCK, EXCLUSIVE-LOCK and SHARE-LOCK
If you don't specify a lock statement then Progress defaults to Share Lock which is bad. You will end up with users deadlocked in a multi user application. You should specify No Lock if you are not updating the records, and Exclusive Lock if you are updating the records. 
Each table in a query needs a specific lock statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When a Progress Openedge program like yours runs with no output, it's a sign no records match the criteria. Query the tables separately, make sure they have records and hard-code some codes you're sure as present to test functionality. Your syntax seems to be correct, so it's most likely a data-related issue.